# Конвертер систем счисления на php?

Tags: php, битовые-операции

Помогите разобраться в основах.
1 байт = 8 бит
В 1 байте может максимум уместиться максимум 255 значений

Число 10010101110 в двочной системе = 1198 в десятичной системе исчисления

Вопрос: Как сделать такой перевод на PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть функция [bindec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.bindec.php), как раз то что Вам нужно. Для обратной конвертации [decbin](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.decbin.php)

`echo bindec('10010101110');`